# How to clone contents inside a div to other div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I display the contents of user updated div(container1) in other div (container2)

```
 <div id="container1">
   <div id="slide1"> Content here include input box, select dropdown, normal text </div>
   <div id="slide2"> Editable Table </div> 
   <div id="slide3"> Editable images </div>

   //Each slide will be hidden after it is updated
</div>

<div id="container2">
//Basically this is editable summary of all the slides
//But by using clone, only empty text box/dropdowns are displayed
//How to display the contents of updated slide1, slide2 and slide3 so that it can be editable like in previous container1 (replicating the container1)

</div>
```

Comment: use clone to get it done.

Comment: i'm really wondering why you have tagged question with `html5-canvas` & `CSS`. Don't spam tag...

Comment: @suchit-kumar  using clone is returning empty input box (it's not including the updated data to the clones)

Comment: @A.Wolff  I had to use canvas and some styling in my design, didn't mean to spam, thought there could be any solution to above question.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to append:

```
$("#container2").append($("#container1").clone().children());
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/a1qq2vde/1/)

If you want to replace:

```
$("#container2").empty().append($("#container1").clone().children());
```

Comment: this would result in invalid HTML markup coz of IDs

Comment: @A.Wolff I thought `unwrap` would solve that but apparently not!

Comment: firstly OP shouldn't use them if he plans to clone them

Comment: True, but then he is cloning the *contents* rather than the divs themselves

Comment: @RGraham Thanks for the quick response, but when i'm trying to replace/clone a canvas image along with some background image then the cloned/replaced/modified canvas is not retaining the changes done before. unlike normal text

Answer (score 2):

With jquery:

```
$("#container2").html($("#container1").html());
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
  $(function() {

   $("#click").click(function(){
    $("#container2").append($("#container1").clone());
   });
   });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container1">
   <div id="slide1"> Content here include input box, select dropdown, normal text </div>
   <div id="slide2"> Editable Table </div> 
   <div id="slide3"> Editable images </div>
</div>

<div id="container2">

</div>
 <button id="click">Clone It!</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

use this 
$("#container2").append($("#container1").html());